Pandas reset_index() not working on grouped dataframe
I have a dataframe df as follows:




Year
Month
Rate




0
2022
1
0.1


1
2022
2
0.1


2
2022
3
0.1


3
2022
4
0.1


4
2022
5
0.1


5
2022
6
0.1


6
2022
7
0.1


7
2022
8
0.1


8
2022
9
0.1


9
2022
10
0.1


10
2022
11
0.1


11
2022
12
0.1


12
2023
1
0.2


13
2023
2
0.2


14
2023
3
0.2


15
2023
4
0.2


16
2023
5
0.2


17
2023
6
0.2


18
2023
7
0.2


19
2023
8
0.2


20
2023
9
0.2


21
2023
10
0.2


22
2023
11
0.2


23
2023
12
0.2



I  need to get the years as the column headers, so I ran the following code:
result = df.groupby([df.Month, df.Year]).sum().unstack()
Output:




Rate





Year
2022
2023


Month




1
0.1
0.2


2
0.1
0.2


3
0.1
0.2


4
0.1
0.2


5
0.1
0.2


6
0.1
0.2


7
0.1
0.2


8
0.1
0.2


9
0.1
0.2


10
0.1
0.2


11
0.1
0.2


12
0.1
0.2



When I try to reset the index and clean up the headers, reset_index() does not seem to be working.
Here is the code I tried :
result.columns = result.columns.droplevel(0)
result.reset_index(inplace = True)
result.reset_index( drop  = True)
print(result)

Output:



Year
Month
2022
2023




0
1
0.1
0.2


1
2
0.1
0.2


2
3
0.1
0.2


3
4
0.1
0.2


4
5
0.1
0.2


5
6
0.1
0.2


6
7
0.1
0.2


7
8
0.1
0.2


8
9
0.1
0.2


9
10
0.1
0.2


10
11
0.1
0.2


11
12
0.1
0.2



I would like to get rid of Year as the index but whatever I try, I can't seem to get to this or even rename it to nothing
I even tried  df.pivot but I run into the same problem

Does something like this works for you? https://onecompiler.com/python/42epb9p3x

IIUC you want .rename_axis():
result = result.droplevel(0, axis=1).reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
print(result)

Prints:
    Month  2022  2023
0       1   0.1   0.2
1       2   0.1   0.2
2       3   0.1   0.2
3       4   0.1   0.2
4       5   0.1   0.2
5       6   0.1   0.2
6       7   0.1   0.2
7       8   0.1   0.2
8       9   0.1   0.2
9      10   0.1   0.2
10     11   0.1   0.2
11     12   0.1   0.2


As you tried, you could use pivot for this. You just have to reset_index after that.
df.pivot(columns="Year", 
         values="Rate", 
         index="Month").rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()

